# add Active Class with localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm struggling with adding an 'active' class using jquery and localStorage when clicking on an 'a' link.

This is the layout I'm using:

```
    <div class="ordering-box" style="display: inline-block;">

        <?php $order_method = JRequest::getVar("orderto", ""); ?>
            <?php $order_method = $moduleParams->ordering_default_method; ?>

                <span class="ordering-box-text">chronologisch</span>

                <a class="order-by" href="#" onclick="document.K2Filter<?php echo $moduleId; ?>.orderto.value='asc'; submit_form_<?php echo $moduleId; ?>(); return false;">
                    <img class="ph" src="<?php echo JURI::base()."templates/template-src"?>/images/icons/chevron-down.png">
                </a>

                <a class="order-by" href="#" onclick="document.K2Filter<?php echo $moduleId; ?>.orderto.value='desc'; submit_form_<?php echo $moduleId; ?>(); return false;">
                    <img class="active-order" src="<?php echo JURI::base()."templates/template-src"?>/images/icons/chevron-up.png">
                </a>

    </div>
```

And this is the JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

$(function () {
    $('.order-by').click(function () {

        $('.order-by > img').siblings().removeClass('active-order');
        $('.order-by > img').addClass('active-order');

        var activeIndex = $(this).index();
        localStorage.setItem('mySelectValue', activeIndex);
    });

});



jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

    var activeIndex = localStorage.getItem('mySelectValue');

    if (isNan(activeIndex)) {
        console.log('nothing stored');
    } else {
        $('.order-by > img').addClass('active-order');

    }
});
```

The idea behind this is when clicking on the the correct 'a' link, the underlying img gets an active class (just a bg color). Since the browser refreshes on click, I'm using localStorage to take it on the next on load... what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `isNan` is wrong, you should use `isNaN`. Check console for errors. Also, using `isNaN` is incorrect here: you should check for `null`, because it's what is returned if no value is stored.

Also, replace `$('.order-by > img')` with `$('.order-by > img').eq(activeIndex)`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Andrew Dunai said, you should check for null when reading from local storage.

`$('.order-by > img').siblings().removeClass('active-order');`

In this line, you are removing the class from the image's siblings but not the actual image so remove `.siblings()`.

When you are reading from local storage and trying to add the class to the active order, you are selecting every image. You need to specify a specific one which matches the index stored in local storage. I'm using `eq()` here.

```
if (activeIndex === null) {
  console.log('nothing stored');
} else {
  $('.order-by > img').removeClass('active-order'); // remove active class from all
  $('.order-by').eq(activeIndex).find('img').addClass('active-order'); // add class to specified order
}
```

Also, when storing the index, you need to be aware that the `span.ordering-box-text` will be at index 0 so you should decrement the index by 1.

`localStorage.setItem('mySelectValue', $(this).index() - 1); // -1 because there is a span at index 0`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkq9guz7/1/)